# How to web scraping graph data?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, web-scraping, data-science

I'm currently working on a personal small machine learning project to predict action figure prices, the first thing I need is data obviously.

I want to collect the price history data from here:
https://www.actionfigure411.com/transformers/war-for-cybertron-siege-series/deluxe-class/ironhide-3664.php

Have been stuck on this for a couple hours, I appreciate for any advices.

By the way, this is just one item, wonder if there's a way to do multiple items efficiently.

Would be also appreciated for any suggestions about handling the data, like features, target variable, etc.

Tried figuring out how to collect graph data, didn't work out.

Comment: I would start by inspecting the page to see if that data is in the page anywhere. It might be in some JavaScript code. Look at the Sources tab and look at any JavaScript files that the page uses.

Comment: Tried that but I'm not that familiar with JavaScript, someone posted a solution and it works. Now, I'm working on multiple items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is embedded in the page inside `<script>` tag. To parse it you can use following example:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.actionfigure411.com/transformers/war-for-cybertron-siege-series/deluxe-class/ironhide-3664.php"

html_doc = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r"jsonData = ({.*?})\n\s*\n", html_doc, flags=re.S).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

for row in data['rows']:
    print('{:<20} ${:<10}'.format(row['c'][0]['v'], row['c'][1]['v']))
```

Prints:

```
Date(2021, 10)       $71        
Date(2021, 11)       $87        
Date(2022, 0)        $90        
Date(2022, 1)        $89        
Date(2022, 2)        $82        
Date(2022, 5)        $58        
Date(2022, 8)        $50        
Date(2022, 9)        $29        
Date(2022, 10)       $57        
Date(2022, 11)       $42        
Date(2023, 0)        $42        
Date(2023, 1)        $100
```

Comment: Really appreciate for the work, this is exactly what I need. Would like to ask, do you think it's possible to collect the graph data for multiple items?https://www.actionfigure411.com/transformers/war-for-cybertron-siege-series-price-guide.php#334

Comment: @user21352273 Looking at the source code, it's just standard `<table>` tags, you can try `pd.read_html` on the source, it should work.